# Build command in sublime text has stopped functioning

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am a new user of  Sublime text.

It has been working fine for a few days until it began to refuse to compile anything and I don't know where the problem is. I wrote python programs and pressed cmd+b and nothing happened. When I try to launch repl for this file - that also doesn't work. I haven't installed any plugins and before this issue all has been working well.

Any suggestions on how to identify/fix the problem are greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you make sure to specify that your file was a Python file on the bottom-right before trying `Ctrl+B`?

Comment: A couple of other things to check.  Is Tools>build system set to automatic? Is Python still available on the search path listed in the build system file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you might want to give more detail. Have you made sure you have saved the file as .py? Try something simple like Print "Hello" and then see if this works.